# Grid 960: how to change width, padding and margin?

Tags: html, css, 960.gs

Is it possible to apply the Grid 960 framework to any existing layout without any visual changes?

The "gutter" sets the distance between every column to a fixed value, what if I need to have a 20px margin instead?

The 960 framework sets the width of columns to a fixed value too. What if I need 2 columns of 231px and 131px ?

Thanks for any hints!

Comment: Why would you need a grid system if you don't want to stick to the grid width?

Comment: If you want a flexible grid, try Twitter Bootstrap....

Answer (score 1):

You can genegate grid css file with custom gutter and column width.
About your second case, the only solution i see is sort out the suitable column width.

For e.g :

If you need column with **231px** width you can generate grid file fith

**gutter =0** and column **width = 21px**,

so you can get 231px width div applying class "**grid_11**", but with these settings is **impossible** to get 131px width div, the closest width you can set is 126px, applying class "grid_6".